# Can I make a pointer to a GameObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pointers

I'm making a card game-type thing in Unity and so therefore have a central "deck" that I need the hand class to be able to access and draw from, but I can't seem to make a pointer to the GameObject, or the deck within the GameObject. Ideally the cards drawn should be removed from the central deck and moved into the hand, but the hand instead has it's own copy of the deck it draws from. This is the code I tried for taking a pointer to the GameObject, I also tried the same thing with the deck within the DeckHolder script but to no avail either.

```
`GameObject* holder = &GameObject.Find("obj_tempDeckHolder");`
```

Comment: why a pointer instead of a reference?

Comment: A `GameObject` is already a reference type, so "making a pointer to it" doesn't make sense, since it already works like a pointer

Comment: you can use 'unsafe' code to get pointer , but why you need it ? it is reference type , just link it well.

Answer (score 0):

U don't have to use pointers in c#.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Yes<sup>1</sup> but you probably don't need pointers<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Unity uses C#. As opposed to compiled languages like C and C++ C# is a managed language that adds a layer between the code you write and the binary code, which layer "manages" potentially unsafe features like accessing unintended memory through indexing an array out of its bounds, or creating memory leaks by allocating memory and not freeing it. Both examples imply use of pointers.
So C# doesn't *usually* let you use pointers except for when you really need them (and know what you're doing) in which case you create an "unsafe context" wherever you declare and reference a pointer like f.i.:

```
public unsafe struct Point2D
{
    public int* x;
    public int* y;
}
```

Or even:

```
public struct Point2D
{
    public unsafe int* x;
    public unsafe int* y;
}
```

Unity supports this via "Allow 'unsafe' Code" setting in Project Settings > Player.

<sup>2</sup> Even if you used pointers, I don't see how it would automatically remove the cards from the center deck and add it to the hand.
One quick approach to what you want is making the central deck a `HashSet<GameObject>` to ensure no card duplicates ever exist. If you do want duplicates then a `List<GameObject>` is most fit. So f.i.

```
//using System.Collections.Generic;
HashSet<GameObject> centralDeck = new HashSet<GameObject>();
```

Each hand (player) would also be/have a `HashSet` or `List`.
For simplicity let's see how to do it with existing `centralDeck` and `hand1` as `List`s. While drawing top 3 cards you'd just do inside a method:

```
  // create references to hold objects to transfer
GameObject[] cardsDrawn = new GameObject[3];
  // actually populate them; 'GameObject' is a reference type so copies are created
  // but they point to the same actual objects
centralDeck.CopyTo(0, cardsDrawn, 0, 3);
  // don't use those references for performance reasons;
  // you know those *are* the same objects
centralDeck.RemoveRange(0, 3);
  // now the go's are not part of centralDeck anymore but they still exist
  // and pointed to by cardsDrawn

  // put them in hand1
hand1.AddRange(cardsDrawn);
  // now when the method returns, the copies will be left to garbage collector
```

Here I tried to condense the code in 4 lines and not use loops but it's even more readable/straightforward with loops.
For 1 card at a time you do:

```
GameObject cardDrawn = centralDeck[0];
centralDeck.Remove(cardDrawn);
hand1.Add(cardDrawn);
```

and you can just put this inside a `for` loop. Note that you type `centralDeck[0]` even in a `for` loop, not `centralDeck[i]`, as the list gets "refreshed" in between the iterations.